# Retrieving git branches in a bash array

Tags: bash, git, branch

I would like to list all git branches which name contain a certain string in an array on a bash script. Seems I can do it to some degree, it just does not look like an array. This is what I've tried:

```
param1="feature"

branches=$(git branch | cut -c 3- | grep $param1);
echo $branches;
echo ${branches[0]};
```

I would like the output to be:

```
feature/my_branch_1 feature/my_branch_2 feature/my_branch_3
feature/my_branch_1
```

I get instead:

```
feature/my_branch_1 feature/my_branch_2 feature/my_branch_3
feature/my_branch_1 feature/my_branch_2 feature/my_branch_3
```

Comment: btw, `${branches[0]}` has a handy shorthand: `$branches`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To assign to an array, you need to use parentheses.

```
branches=($(git branch | cut -c 3- | grep feature))
#        ~                                        ~
```